# Transferring PS3 PsPlus to Ps4 and keeping games

Tags: ps3, psn, ps4

I am thinking of getting a PSplus subscription. What I currently have is a PS3 but in the future I will buy (sometime) a PS4. Will the games that I acquire now from my subscription on PS4 redeemable if I get the PS4 a lot later? (as long as still pay for the subscription of course)

Comment: You can't *transfer* a PS Plus account, because your subscription is for your whole account, regardless of which platforms you're actually using. As long as you **claim** the games, you should be able to download them later as they will be added to your download list. You have to actively claim them though, it doesn't happen automatically. The PS4 games will probably not show up in the store on your PS3, but you can log in at https://store.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/ and claim them from there, which means adding them to the basket as free and proceed to checkout, as if you were buying them.

Comment: I wasn't sure if I should answer, because I thought it's a duplicate of the other question. But I guess it doesn't make a difference anyway :)

Comment: Well here's the thing. In SO I made a question that ended up being a duplicate. But now it has more than 16k views because the wording is a lot different and google search leads to that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't *transfer* a PS Plus account, because your subscription is for your whole account, regardless of which platforms you're actually using.

As long as you **claim** the games, you should be able to download them later as they will be added to your download list. You have to actively claim them though, it doesn't happen automatically. The PS4 games will probably not show up in the store on your PS3, but you can log in at https://store.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/ and claim them from there, which means adding them to the basket as free and proceed to checkout, as if you were buying them.